# how to read data from byte array from java

Tags: java, mp3, arrays

i convert a mp3 file into byte array and i read from byte array but it shows null pointer exception on line number 15
my code:

```
public class MainClass {
    static byte[] bytesarray = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\taxi.mp3");
            try {
                fis.read(bytesarray, 0, 32);
                System.out.println(bytesarray.length);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesarray);
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            int c;
            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    System.out.print((char) c);
                } else {
                    System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase((char) c));
                }
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static byte[] bytesarray = new byte[32];` should do the work, you didn't initialize your array...

See the [documentation of read](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: If you don't hardcoded the array to null like this: "static byte[] bytesarray = null;", then you might actually get warned that you are trying to access an uninitialized variable. For this reason, it's best practice in Java NOT to initialize your values to null, false etc. Unlike in C where this is actually recommended...

Answer (score 1):

```
static byte[] bytesarray = new byte[32];
```